Translation into Omniscript standard error message
How can I translate the default error message when setting the element as required in an omniscript?


This can definitely be achieved in a Multi-Language OmniScript. It may be possible in a single-language OmniScript as well, however from a brief test, I haven't had great results.
Multi-Language OmniScripts provide much greater flexibility regarding custom labels and translating (most) of an OmniScript.
Each standard piece of text in an OmniScript will be present in your org as a 'custom label', which you will be able to provide translations for as required.
In short:

If you haven't already, enable translation workbench for your desired language(s)
Find which label(s) you want to translate by referring to the OmniScript Custom Label Reference (Salesforce Documentation)
Find the custom label to translate (i.e. OmniRequiredWithLabel) and provide a translation
Create a multi-language OmniScript, and test in the desired language using the 'language' option in preview

I would recommend reading up on the multi-language OmniScript documentation here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_create_multi_language_omniscripts.htm&type=5

Example:
OmniRequiredWithLabel custom label, updated with a German translation:

Multi-Language OmniScript created with a required question:

Previewing the OmniScript in German (see 'Language' option next to theme in the preview), the custom label translation now appears as expected:

